# Send and receive data code using OpenSSL

Tags: c++, security, openssl

I need to send and receive data. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810795/how-to-fix-openssl-incorrect-data-transferring) is solution for my original problem. I want to know how safe my finished code is and how I can improve it. [Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100811/send-and-receive-data-code) is my first try. Now I need to get review for my new code.

```
void sslWrite(SSL *ssl, const void *buf, unsigned size)
{
    int writedTotal = 0;
    const char *ccBuf = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(buf);

    while (writedTotal < size) {
        int writedPart = SSL_write(ssl, ccBuf + writedTotal, size - writedTotal);
        if (writedPart < 0) {
            std::string error = "SSL_write error = ";
            error += (std::to_string(writedPart) + ".");
            throw std::runtime_error(error);
        }
        writedTotal += writedPart;
    }
}

std::vector<char> sslRead(SSL *ssl, unsigned size)
{
    std::vector<char> ret(size);
    unsigned readTotal = 0;

    while (readTotal < size) {
        int readPart = SSL_read(ssl, &ret[readTotal], size - readTotal);
        if (readPart < 0) {
            std::string error = "SSL_read error = ";
            error += (std::to_string(readPart) + ".");
            throw std::runtime_error(error);
        }
        readTotal += readPart;
    }

    return ret;
}

void sslWriteSize(SSL *ssl, unsigned size)
{
    if (sizeof(u_long) > 8)
        throw std::runtime_error("Write size error.");

    u_long nlSize = htonl(size);
    sslWrite(ssl, &nlSize, 8);
}

unsigned sslReadSize(SSL *ssl)
{
    if (sizeof(u_long) > 8)
        throw std::runtime_error("Read size error.");

    u_long size = *reinterpret_cast<u_long *>(&sslRead(ssl, 8)[0]);
    size = ntohl(size);
    return size;
}

void sslWrite(SSL *ssl, const std::string &data)
{
    if (data.empty())
        throw std::runtime_error("SSL write error. Data is empty.");

    sslWriteSize(ssl, data.size());
    sslWrite(ssl, &data.at(0), data.size());
}

std::vector<char> sslRead(SSL *ssl)
{
    unsigned size = sslReadSize(ssl);
    return sslRead(ssl, size);
}
```

Is there a buffering problem as in my old code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks good. No buffering problems anymore. Endianness is handled correctly. Reading and writing size is duly factored out.

The only suggestion is not rely on the native `unsigned` type to represent the size. Notice that `htonl` takes `uint32_t` as a parameter. It is a strong hint to pass size as `uint32_t` as well. This guarantees that the size is 4 byte long no matter which platform it is running on. Don't forget to `#include <cstdint>`.

Comment: Do I have only replace `unsigned` to `uint32_t`?

Comment: @Ufx Precisely.

Comment: Can I make palpably faster this code?

Answer (score 1):

I would change two things and one bug.

1: Checking for compatability is a compile time option.

```
if (sizeof(u_long) > 8)
    throw std::runtime_error("Read size error.");

// prefer to generate compile time errors when you can.

static_assert(sizeof(u_long) > 8, "Only support systems with the correct size");
```

2: Make your functions symmetric. If you have a write string then I would expect a read string. If you have a read vector I would expect a write vector.

3: Don't use `at()` unless you are validating user input. In this case it will throw an exception if the size of your string is 0. I would still expect your code to work correctly for zero sized strings.

```
 sslWrite(ssl, &data.at(0), data.size());   // throws for zero sized strings.

 sslWrite(ssl, &data[0], data.size());
```

> Is there a buffering problem as in my old code?

I bet the SSL layer is already buffering this. There is no point in doing it twice. But its always worth reading the documentation to check.